# Dagger2: How to inject field without injection of it's compositor class?

Tags: java, dagger-2

My Class A needs Dependency injection of Class C.
C class is component of B class (B has C as a field).
Can Class A inject C without B injection?

**[A injected]->(B not injected to A)->[C injected to B]**

I my real project I need to inject field to one class but don't need adding injection queue to the all classes contains (directly or indirectly) this field.

Currently I have Exception in B class:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at B.log(B.java:28)
        at A.b_foo(A.java:28)
        at App.main(App.java:36)
```

Please advice.
Code:

App.java

```
import dagger.Component;
import javax.inject.Singleton;
 
public class App {
  @Singleton
  @Component(
      modules = {
              CModule.class
             }
  )
  public interface AppRunner {
    A instance();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    AppRunner appRunner = DaggerApp_AppRunner.builder().build();
    appRunner.instance().foo();
  }
}
```

A.java

```
import javax.inject.Inject;

public class A {
    private final B b;

    @Inject
    A() {
        this.b = new B();
    }

    public void foo() {
        b.log();
    }
}
```

B.java

```
import javax.inject.Inject;

public class B {

  @Inject
  C c;

  B() { }

  public void log() {
      c.log("in C log"); //java.lang.NullPointerException here because B was not injected before C
  }
}
```

C.java

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Singleton
public final class C {
  private final List<String> logs = new ArrayList<>();

  @Inject
  C() {}

  public void log(String msg) {
    logs.add(msg);
  }
}
```

CModule.java

```
import dagger.Module;
import dagger.Provides;

@Module
public abstract class CModule {
    @Provides
  static C provideC() {
        return new C();
    }
}
```

Update: Can I have fully working code without B injection at all? My A class knows  about Dagger. But A must don't have B injection.

Comment: What is `AppRunner` and `DaggerApp_AppRunner`? Please provide a [mcve]. Can you use @Inject for the constructor instead on the fields? That way you are forced to create the object `B` with an object `C` (you get from somewhere).

Comment: @Progman, minimal reproducible example already provided. All classes are above. AppRunner declared. DaggerApp_AppRunner generated in runtime by Dagger.

Comment: Is it an option to inject a `Provider<C>` in your `A` class as described on https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/#provider-injections? That way you can use the `get()` method to get the `C` object and call the constructor of `B` with the instance of the `C` class.

Comment: @Progman, in my real project I will have too much get calls in this case. In this example I have only one B class, but in my real project I have 10 classes like B class in the chain from A to C.

Comment: Would injecting a `Provider<B>` into the class `A` work? That way you can request a `B` object on demand from dagger instead of using `new B();` "manually". This should also inject all the other dependencies like the annotated `C` field in `B`.

Comment: @Progman, Yes it will work. BUT I don't want to change all 10 classes with adding Inject annotation to its' code. My question is: How to inject field without injection of it's compositor classes (too much classes)? Thank you for being with me in this issue.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to elaborate on why using the approach with `Provider<C>` (and `new B(providerForC.get())`) or with `Provider<B>` will not work for you or what the problems are. Based on the comments it looks like `Provider<B>` might be what you want to do, but it's difficult to tell what the problems are and what the problems with the other "10 classes" are.

Comment: What do you mean by "fully working code without B injection at all"? You are missing crucial information on the problem you have and why you have to "cut" the Dagger chain of `@Inject` fields. Keep in mind that when you use `new B();` manually you are responsible for that object, not Dagger. This also means that you have to set all the fields by yourself (with or without help of the Dagger API).

Answer (score 2):

You have an `@Inject` field in class `B`, and you want to be able to get a fully initialized `B` within `A`

#### Option 1: Just add `@Inject` to the constructor

That's it.  You don't need to move the dependencies into the constructor.

```
public class B {

  @Inject
  C c;

  @Inject // This annotation is the only thing added.
  B() { }

  public void log() {
      c.log("in C log");
  }
}
```

If even this is more than you want to change (or can change) in `B`, read on.

#### Option 2: Inject a `MembersInjector<B>`

Dagger contains the interface [`MembersInjector`](https://dagger.dev/api/latest/dagger/MembersInjector.html), which does exactly what it sounds like.  You can inject `MembersInjector<B>` into `A`, and use that to construct `B` in two steps.

```
@Inject
A(MembersInjector<B> injector) {
    this.b = new B();
    injector.injectMembers(b);
}
```

Since `MembersInjector` is part of Dagger and not JSR-330, this means that class `A` necessarily has knowledge about Dagger.  This is probably an issue, but you can easily move this logic out of `A`:

#### Option 3: Use `MembersInjector` in a `@Provides` method.

```
@Module
class BModule {
    @Provides
    static B provideB(MembersInjector<B> injector) {
        B b = new B();
        injector.injectMembers(b);
        return b;
    }
}
```

Now you can inject `B` or `Provider<B>` anywhere, without modifying `B` at all.

Comment: Nice answer. Can I have fully working code without B injection at all? My A class knows  about Dagger. But A must don't have B injection.